# Quickbooks get all Write Cheques

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I'm new with integrating quickbooks in C#, is there a simple way to query all the list of cheque in Quickbooks.

From Banking Menu > Write Cheques
There you can add cheques, now i would like to query all the cheque that I created.

[image]

I'm currently trying a lot of code from the net but still I'm having a hard time reading it.
Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Did you check the product's documentation? Does it have an API you can call? What have you tried?

Comment: HI, add some code... and specify what platform you are using, SDK, QBXML,online API?